# opc ua client implementation using eclipse milo

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I am trying to do the implementation of opc ua client using eclipse milo sdk and the reference link am using is:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/176894/opc-ua-client-performance-with-eclipse-milo.html

for the **Publish/Subscribe code** since am having multiple nodes am not able to make out the data that I get corresponds to which node id and also the timestamp I am getting am not able to make out its in which format.

```
Item: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.OpcUaMonitoredItem@2b2c39b1
Value: DataValue{value=Variant{value=11}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, 
sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=131771575305048867, javaDate=Fri Jul 27 15:02:10 IST 2018},
serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=131771575305048867, javaDate=Fri Jul 27 15:02:10 IST 2018}}
```

and when am using **Async Read code** am not getting timestamp.

```
[DataValue{value=Variant{value=3}, 
status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1601}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1601}}, 

DataValue{value=Variant{value=11}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1601}, 
serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1601}}, 

DataValue{value=Variant{value=8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, 
sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1601}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1601}}]
```

can anyone give me some idea on where am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to understand if you started with the examples from Milo itself, rather than a random benchmark someone wrote using Milo that you happened to stumble across.

Check out the examples:

[Subscribe Example](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/master/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/SubscriptionExample.java)

[Read Example](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/master/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/ReadExample.java)